# How to display non-printable Ascii characters?

Tags: c#, console, ascii

I came across this simple code to output ascii to the console:

```
Console.Write((char)1); //Output ☺
```

The thing is, it only works when I change the fonts of the console to RasterFonts, and it's ugly. I mean, look at those old text-based games, how did they draw some ascii art like this?

[The Amazing Adventures of ANSI Dude](http://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/amazing-adventures-of-ansi-dude/screenshots), [Snipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipes_(video_game)#/media/File:Snipes_-_Text_mode_game_by_Novell_-_screen_grab_Apr05.gif)

How can I draw nice Ascii on that console?

Comment: It would be so much easier if you could use Unicode to do so... "\u263a" would produce face you are looking for, and the table drawing characters http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/box-drawing/ would do the rest.

Comment: Well that was fast, and thank you so much, works as expected! :)

Comment: Agreeing with @AlexeiLevenkov, if you want '☺' just use '☺' (or '\u263a'). If you use '\u0001\' you are relying on the historically convenient multiple mapping from both '\u263a' and '\u0001\' to CP437 code point 1.

Answer (score 1):

Unless for some reason you are restricted to use [ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) you should use proper Unicode characters. It will avoid potential conflicts with mapping control characters (0-31) to printable characters and let you use lines and borders directly with .Net `String` type without going through encodings (since line and borders are part of "extended ASCII" and not mapped directly to Unicode characters unlike regular 7 bit ASCII codes 1-127).

Unicode `"\u263a"` would produce face you are looking for. For the borders and lines drawing use characters from Unicode [box drawing range](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf), for more characters see overall table http://unicode.org/charts/.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, although some of the Unicode characters are only displaying "?"... I wonder if there's a way to get those nice looking characters! Like I was thinking of doing a chess game with the Unicode, but they're not working!

Comment: @SirMaxwell not every font supports all characters. "Segoe UI" (assuming you use Windows) generally support the most ranges.

Comment: Ohh and is there a way to use that font in the console without having to write a long low-level code just to implement it?

Comment: @SirMaxwell you can't... I should have mentioned that as Segoe is not monospace font - you may try changing default font (http://superuser.com/questions/965086/change-the-default-console-window-font-in-windows-10) or finding different one (some tips - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/)... But if you looking into using less common characters in console app you'd be better off switching to GUI apps and pick whatever fonts you like (you still may simulate console-like appearance if you want to)